# Add row duplicate on condition in an SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

Suppose having two data rows:

```
with
 data_table (title, val_a, val_b) as ( 
    select 'A', 1, 1 from dual union all 
    select 'B', 1, 2 from dual
 ) 
 select *
   from data_table;
```

I would like to create an SQL query, which duplicates a row when `VAL_A <> VAL_B`, returning three rows like:

```
| TITLE | VAL_A | VAL_B |  MARKER    |
--------------------------------------
|  'A'  |  1    |  1    | 'SINGLE'   |
|  'B'  |  1    |  2    | 'MULTIPLE' |
|  'B'  |  1    |  2    | 'MULTIPLE' |
```

And it is NOT appropriate to select twice from large table `data_table` (UNION ALL, ...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a self-JOIN with inequality :

```
with
 data_table (title, val_a, val_b) as ( 
    select 'A', 1, 1 from dual union all 
    select 'B', 1, 2 from dual
 ) 
 select d1.*, nvl2(d2.title,'MULTIPLE','SINGLE') as marker
   from data_table d1
   left join data_table d2 on d1.val_a <> d1.val_b
  where d2.val_a is null
     or ( d2.val_a is not null and d2.val_a = d2.val_b );
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=821052af797716599a46b64a0d16922e)</kbd>

Comment: Feels cleaner than a union query for some reason +1.

Comment: Looks brilliant even without a demo.

Comment: thank you @forpas for the caveat, `or d1.val_a > d1.val_b` added related to exceptional cases.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan the problem is the join and the condition. Still does not work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fb1ab4f0b1b99d05f398e7a81545ce52

Comment: @forpas but the demo your provided works depending on `MULTIPLES` and `SINGLE` cases.

Comment: In the results there are 4 rows with title = 'B'. Shouldn't it be 2 rows? Am I missing something?

Comment: :) but is says `MULTIPLE` not `DOUBLE` @forpas

Comment: From the question: *...which duplicates a row when VAL_A <> VAL_B...* doesn't it mean to have that row 2 times?

Comment: OK, I made it duplicate(instead of ordinary multiple) by adding extra where condition @forpas

Comment: I did not test it, it seems ok, but change `on d1.val_a < d1.val_b or d1.val_a > d1.val_b` to `on d1.val_a <> d1.val_b`

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, another approach that (ab)uses a recursive CTE (11gR2+):

```
with
 data_table (title, val_a, val_b) as ( 
    select 'A', 1, 1 from dual union all 
    select 'B', 1, 2 from dual
 ),
 tmp (title, val_a, val_b, marker, flag) as (
    select d.*,
           case when val_a <> val_b then 'MULTIPLE' else 'SINGLE' end,
           case when val_a <> val_b then 1 else 0 end
      from data_table d
    union all
    select title, val_a, val_b, marker, 0
      from tmp
      where flag = 1
 )
 select title, val_a, val_b, marker
   from tmp
  order by title, val_a, val_b;

TITLE      VAL_A      VAL_B MARKER  
----- ---------- ---------- --------
A              1          1 SINGLE  
B              1          2 MULTIPLE
B              1          2 MULTIPLE
```

The anchor member uses a case expression to decide if that row is single or multiple, and also to set a flag; which the recursive member uses to terminate.

In this scenario it terminates after one iteration, which might well seem like overkill. If required though it could be adapted to produce several extra rows, e.g. one for each of the difference between the two values:

```
with
 data_table (title, val_a, val_b) as ( 
    select 'A', 1, 1 from dual union all 
    select 'B', 1, 2 from dual union all
    select 'C', 4, 7 from dual
 ),
 tmp (title, val_a, val_b, marker, flag) as (
    select d.*,
           case when val_a <> val_b then 'MULTIPLE' else 'SINGLE' end,
           abs(val_b - val_a)
      from data_table d
    union all
    select title, val_a, val_b, marker, flag - 1
      from tmp
      where flag > 0
 )
 select title, val_a, val_b, marker
   from tmp
  order by title, val_a, val_b;
TITLE      VAL_A      VAL_B MARKER  
----- ---------- ---------- --------
A              1          1 SINGLE  
B              1          2 MULTIPLE
B              1          2 MULTIPLE
C              4          7 MULTIPLE
C              4          7 MULTIPLE
C              4          7 MULTIPLE
C              4          7 MULTIPLE
```

Like I said, just for fun, as that isn't your current requirement *8-)

Answer (score 2):

With UNION ALL for the 2 cases:

```
with
 data_table (title, val_a, val_b) as ( 
    select 'A', 1, 1 from dual union all 
    select 'B', 1, 2 from dual union all 
    select 'C', 3, 3 from dual union all 
    select 'D', 5, 4 from dual
 ) 
select * from (
  select t.*, case when t.val_a <> t.val_b then 'MULTIPLE' else 'SINGLE' end marker
  from data_table t
  union all
  select t.*, 'MULTIPLE'
  from data_table t
  where t.val_a <> t.val_b
)
order by title
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3961781cb19f40822e573e29006a5d78).
Results:

```
> TITLE | VAL_A | VAL_B | MARKER  
> :---- | ----: | ----: | :-------
> A     |     1 |     1 | SINGLE  
> B     |     1 |     2 | MULTIPLE
> B     |     1 |     2 | MULTIPLE
> C     |     3 |     3 | SINGLE  
> D     |     5 |     4 | MULTIPLE
> D     |     5 |     4 | MULTIPLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want `union all`?

```
with data_table (title, val_a, val_b) as ( 
      select 'A', 1, 1 from dual union all 
      select 'B', 1, 2 from dual
     ) 
select *
from data_table
union all
select *
from data_table
where val_a <> val_b;
```

Comment: I wonder if it is appropriate to select twice when a huge query is hidden under the `data_table`. Of course I thought about an `union all` solution, but I'm still looking for something elegant.

Comment: diziaq did You think about triggers after insert ? Meaby it would do the job

Comment: @Kuba Do, it is not about a table contents, I just need to do the trick in any query by different conditions, so `VAL_A <> VAL_B` is just an example of a simple condition.

Comment: @diziaq . . . This answers the question that you asked here.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question, not in a comment.